# AngularJS Ajax get issue

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am a bit new to angular and am scratching my head over this one. my factory `console.log`'s show that the first time through everything is defined correctly, but the factory is for some reason re-evaluating the data I pass it to `undefined`. Here is my code starting with the html input that is passing the data to the controller then to the factory:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Channel" ng-model="channel" ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 && cname(channel)"/>
```

This will send to my controller what is typed in the input field once the enter key is pressed `cnam(channel)`

Controller and Factory:

```
angular.module('youtubePlaylistAppApp')
  .factory('ytVids', function($http){

    return{
        getChannel: function(name){
            console.log('name: '+name);
            var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername='+ name +'&key=[my api key]';
            console.log(url);
            return $http.get(url);
        },
        getVids: function(channel){
            console.log('channel: '+ channel);
            return     $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId='+channel+'&key=[my api key]')
            .success(function(response){
                //console.log(response.items);

                return response.items;
            });

        }
    };
  })
  .controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope, ytVids) {
     $scope.cname = function(channel){
        console.log(channel);
        ytVids.getChannel(channel);
        ytVids.getChannel().success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads);
        ytVids.getVids(response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads)
        .success(function(data){
                console.log(data.items);
                $scope.ytChannel = data.items;
            });
        });
    };
  });
```

Here is the output I am seeing in my console dev tools after enter is pressed when typing in the input field:

the first console log `console.log(channel);` console logs the correct response. If I type "freddiew" and press enter, that is what is logged

Then I pass that into my factory `ytVids.getChannel(channel);` and console log in the factory `console.log('name: '+name);` This logs the correct response as in `name: freddiew`

I then declare a variable `var url =` and give it the youtube url and concat the channel name with the url

I then console log the variable and get what is expected `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=freddiew&key=[my api key]'`

This url works when I have tried it in postman and just hard coding a name in. but passing in the name, the console then spits out some more logs which I dont know why, and it looks like it overides the url I just built out to make the call because this is what is logged from the factory:

`name: freddiew`

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=freddiew&key=[my key]`

It is then logged after this as `undefined` and the api call concats `undefined` with the url and makes the api call with this `undefined` url

`name: undefined`

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=undefined&key=[my key]`

`forUsername=` is where the channel name should go.

anyone know why it is being defined as `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have wrong extra service call.

```
  .controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope, ytVids) {
     $scope.cname = function(channel){
        console.log(channel);
        //ytVids.getChannel(channel); <-- you should remove this & passed channel param in below call
        ytVids.getChannel(channel).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads);
        ytVids.getVids(response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads)
        .success(function(data){
                console.log(data.items);
                $scope.ytChannel = data.items;
            });
        });
    };
  });
```

Comment: I didnt even realize! Thanks for seeing that. That would makes sense as to why it was calling it twice....